# Accessing Kurento client app from remote computer

Tags: kurento

I've tried to run one of the tutorials, installed KMS and run the java application in the same remote server, but I want to access the app from my computer.

In the tutorial, all is done from the same machine, and so the address to the web app is https://localhost:port.

I used the ip and hostname of the server instead of localhost but it's not connecting. It can be an issue in the server, but is there something else I have to do to access the app from outside the machine running it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I assumed that the `-Dkms.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento` option was necessary only if the java app was running in a different machine as de KMS, but it's also necessary if the browser from where I access the app is in another machine.